# php replace array key with square brackets to array value

Tags: php, arrays, string, replace

I have a string that contain a mysql query:

```
$string = "UPDATE [table1] SET value = 1 WHERE id = 1";
```

I would like to change [table1] with the value of this array:

```
$table['table1']='pages';
$table['table2']='products';
etc
```

The result should be:

```
mysql_query( $string ); // "UPDATE pages SET value = 1 WHERE id = 1"
```

I already tried the following but nothing:

```
mysql_query( str_replace( '[', '$table[', $string ));
mysql_query( str_replace( array_keys( "[$table]" ), array_values( $table ), $string ));
mysql_query( str_replace( array_keys( "[".$table."]" ), array_values( $table ), $string ));
```

**EDIT**
This way works, but there is no a easiest way?

```
str_replace( explode( ',', ( '['.implode( '],[',array_keys( $table ) ) .']' ) ), $table, $string );
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this

```
$table['table1']='pages';
$table['table2']='products';

$string = "UPDATE [table1] SET value = 1 WHERE id = 1";

foreach($table as $key => $value){
    $string = str_replace('['.$key.']', $value, $string);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about the simple approach?

```
$string = "UPDATE ".$table['table1']." SET value = 1 WHERE id = 1";
```

Comment: No I cannot do that, I have to convert the [table1] with the value of $table[table1]